# Oracle PL-SQL Replace a charecter in the middle of a string

Tags: oracle, replace, plsql, split

I have a stored procedure that retrieve all the data I need in the following format:

```
column 1 | column 2 | ....
text 1   | lorem ipsum doloret & sit amet | ....
text 2   | doloret  | ....
text 3   | sit amet, tu ne quesiri | ....
```

So, since the data will be displayed in a html table, i need to split the second column so it will take the same space (i.e. wrap text).
I was thinking (c# oriented) that if I split the column 2 using space as delimiter and I replace the middle space with a `'<br/>'` it may works, but I have no idea on how to achieve this in PL-SQL (it is mandatory to put the login on the DB side for this project).

Many thanks in advance,
Simone.

Comment: Thanks for the status report. Was there a *question* in there somewhere? Certainly, it's possible to perform string manipulation using SQL expressions. But we have to scratch our heads, and wonder if the database query is the most appropriate spot to inject markup for formatting. It sounds as if you want word wrap enabled.

Comment: @spencer7593 yes, definitely a functionality like the word wrap! :)

Comment: But why do this "formatting" in a SQL query? I'm just not able to understand why you wouldn't you just enable word wrap as a formatting attribute in the HTML, or in the CSS. (I understand this doesn't answer the question you're asking... I'm questioning the rationale behind your question.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it with a bit of creativity, but any better suggestion is appreciated:

```
substr(column2,1,instr(column2,' ',7)-1) || '<br/>' || substr(column2,instr(column2,' ',7)+1
```

Answer (score 1):

use regular expressions, e.g. the following replaces the space with `<br/>` after each word longer than 7 characters:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '([^ ]{7})( )', '\1<br/>')
```

and the next one after at least 7 characters:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '(.{7})( )', '\1<br/>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `replace(trim(column2), ' ', '<br/>')` if you need wrap words by space

Comment: because I don't want to go to the next line after each word but only if the string is longer than the column